# What is std::string(itr, itr) supposed to do?

Tags: c++, iterator, language-lawyer, stdstring

The [web site cplusplus documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/basic_string/basic_string/) for std::string constructor taking two input iterators states in part:

> Copies the sequence of characters in the range [first,last), in the same order.
>
> first, last:
> Input iterators to the initial and final positions in a range. The range used is [first,last), which includes all the characters between first and last, including the character pointed by first but not the character pointed by last.

What does this mean in the degenerate case where `first == last`?  On the one hand `first` is included and on the other `last` is excluded?  What does the official C++ standard say should happen in this case?  Should an exception be thrown?

Comment: The construction of an empty string is not such a degenerate case.

Comment: *The* documentation does not say that.

Comment: @WilliamKF: cplusplus.com is not "The" documentation.  That's someone's summary of the documentation.  Some people also have problems with that website's accuracy, though IMO they seem to have fixed most of the errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what documentation it is you're reading, but *the standard* says (§21.4.2/15):

> [..] constructs a string from the values in the range `[begin, end)`, as indicated in the Sequence Requirements table

And the Sequence requirements table (Table 100) defines `X a(i, j)` for a valid range `[i, j)` as:

> Constructs a sequence container equal to the range `[i, j)`

A range is *valid* when the second iterator is reachable from the first (through incrementing). For two iterators that are equal, the range is empty. See §24.2.1/7:

> A *range* is a pair of iterators that designate the beginning and end of the computation. A range `[i,i)` is an empty range; in general, a range `[i,j)` refers to the elements in the data structure starting with the element pointed to by `i` and up to but not including the element pointed to by `j`. Range `[i,j)` is valid if and only if `j` is reachable from `i`. The result of the application of functions in the library to invalid ranges is undefined.

So if `first == last`, as you say, you will get an empty string. If `last` is not reachable from `first`, you have undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

The range is empty, so there's nothing to copy. The result is an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

> What does this mean in the degenerate case where first == last?

It means that the input range is empty, so the string will be empty.

> What does the standard say should happen in this case?

C++11 24.2.1/7 says:

> A range `[i,i)` is an empty range

Answer (score 0):

One thing I've used it for several times is constructing a `std::string` from a substring in a large C-style string (`const char*`). You can pass it two `const char*` pointers and it will construct a string from the characters starting at the first pointer and ending one before the second pointer.

If `first == last`, the result is an empty string. If `first > last`, behavior is undefined (thanks Mooing Duck)

Comment: That's undefined behavior, no exception is required to be thrown